# Schedule Android Auto Power off & on?

Tags: android

Is there an app that can schedule auto power off & power on?
Like I want it to turn off every night at 10:00pm and turn on every morning at 5:00am.
P.S.: I use a Samsung phone with Android 13

Comment: What Android version?

Comment: By `switch off & switch on` do you mean restart? Please edit your question to make it less ambiguous. Maybe give an example of the schedule you would use. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Samsung phones have this as an inbuilt feature, you don't need any third-party apps.

Here's a [step-by-step instruction](https://www.samsung.com/ph/support/mobile-devices/restart-your-galaxy-phone-regularly-to-prevent-it-from-slowing-down-or-freezing/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20automate%20periodic%20restarts) from Samsung.

- Step 1. Open **Settings**, and then select Battery and device care.
- Step 2. Tap the More options (the **three vertical dot**s).
- Step 3. Select **Automation**.
- Step 4. Tap **Auto restart at set times**.
- Step 5. **Set the Schedule**. Your phone will restart automatically within 1 hour of the time you set.

Comment: Links can disappear.  You could improve your answer by editing it and posting the steps here (as well as providing the link).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks, that option I'm aware.
I'm looking for some option to switch off & switch on based on scheduled time. which was possible in my earlier xiaomi phone

Comment: Does this setting also work if the device is switched off, so that it allows you to auto power on at the specified time? If not this is not a valid answer.